# Generating high volume and velocity data with Yahoo Cloud Serving Benchmark

Tags: networking, velocity, volume, ycsb, bigdata

YSCB offers different type of workloads.

## how can i simulate real time network environment using Yahoo Cloud Serving Benchmark where:

- we can expect communication rate can decrease or increase based on a
  predefined distribution
- size of packets or records can increase or decrease based on a
  predefined distribution.

Basically i want to generate big data traffic using YCSB which can have different VOLUME & VELOCITY

Current YCSB offers static values for volume.
These values can be changed but not varied.

## The number of fields in a record

fieldcount=10

## The size of each field (in bytes)

fieldlength=100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to generate high volume by velocity by using a loop inside a loop and iterating over throughput for velocity  ($j) out side and iterating field count for volume in inner loop ( $i)

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb-async -p fieldcount=$j  -threads 4 -target $i -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://localhost:27017/ycsb?w=0 > /home/concurrent/k
```